# A framed theorem without numbering?

Tags: numbering, theorems, mdframed

Is it possible to draw a frame around a theorem-like `environment` ? If possible, I would like to use `mdframed`.

In the documentation, the general form of the command is given by

```
\newmdtheoremenv[<mdframedoptions>]{<envname>}
[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
```

I wonder if an appropriate `<numberedlike>` could do it.

Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can define a structure using `\mdtheorem` which automatically generates a numbered version and an unnumbered one accessed using the starred version of the name (see the definition and use of `mytheoi` below).
2. Use `\newtheorem*` (from `amsthm` or `ntheorem`) to define an unnumbered structure and then surround it with an mdframed (see `mytheoii` below).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdtheorem[backgroundcolor=cyan]{mytheoi}{Theorem}

\newtheorem*{mytheoii}{Theorem}
\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=orange]{mytheoii}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheoi*}
test
\end{mytheoi*}

\begin{mytheoii}
test
\end{mytheoii}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ntheorem` as in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newtheorem{mytheo}{Remark}
\newframedtheorem{fmytheo}{Remark}
\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo}
This is a remark. It is not framed.
\end{mytheo}

\begin{fmytheo}
This is a remark. It is  framed.
\end{fmytheo}
\end{document}
```

The type of frame can easily be redefined.